# How I can send some data to firebase from React-Native app for tracking user activity?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I have an APP and I would like to track user activity when they make orders. So, when user makes an order I would like to send to Firebase some object like this:

```
{
  productName: 'product',
  id: 1,
  price: 100,
  quantity: 1
}
```

And then in Firebase I would like to see table with this data, for example:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKw12.png)

In my project I use this library for tracking quantity of users `@react-native-firebase/analytics`

```
            firebase
                .analytics()
                .setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(
                    trackingStatus === TRACKIG_STATUS_ENUM.authorized
                );
```

So how to create firebase table like I described and how to send this data from my app?

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
import * as Analytics from 'expo-firebase-analytics'
Analytics.logEvent('new_order', { cart_id : id,product_qty:qty })
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't use expo in my app.

Comment: @wefwefwefwef you don't have to have expo to use this package